# Problems binding models using dynamic nested partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views, editorfortemplate

My question today is how do I deal with complex dynamic nested partial views in MVC 5 applications. The idea is that a customer can add x number of stores and x number of store taxes per payment.

The best way to describe my situation is with the structure of my models:

```
public class PaymentViewModel
{
    public HomeViewModel
    {
       NewStores = new List<StoreViewModel>();
    }
    public IList<StoreViewModel> NewStores { get; set; }
}

public class StoreViewModel
{
    public StoreViewModel
    {
       NewStoreTax = new List<StoreTaxViewModel>();
    }
    public IList<StoreTaxViewModel> NewStoreTaxes { get; set; }
}

public class StoreTaxViewModel
{
    public int TaxId { get; set; };
    public string TaxName { get; set; };
    public decimal TaxRate { get; set; };
}
```

The view Index.cshtml contains the following form:

```
@model PaymentViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   <div id="newStores">
   @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.NewStores.Count(); i++)
   {
     @Html.EditorFor(model => @Model.NewStores[i])
   }
   <div />

   <input type="button" id="addstore" name="addstore" value="Add Store" />
   <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

The editor template for Store.cshtml:

```
@model StoreViewModel
@using ( Html.BeginCollectionItem( "NewStores" ) )
{
   <div id="newStoreTax">
   @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.NewStoreTaxes.Count; i++)
   {
      @Html.EditorFor(model => @Model.NewStoreTaxes[i])
   }
   </div>

   <input type="button" id="addstoretax" name="addstoretax" value="Add Store Tax" />
}
```

Finally the editor template for StoreTax.cshtml:

```
@model StoreTaxViewModel
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("StoreTaxes"))
{
   <dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => @Model.taxName)
    </dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => @Model.taxName)
    </dd>
    </dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor( model => @Model.taxRate)
    </dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => @Model.taxRate)
    </dd>
   </dl>
}
```

Whenever I post to the controller and inspect the model, the list of Store objects have been populated but the lists of StoreTaxes objects inside the Store object is not.

I have the following POST action in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(PaymentViewModel paymentViewModel)
{

}

public ActionResult CreateNewStore()
{
   var storeViewModel = new StoreViewModel();
   return PartialView( "~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/StoreViewModel.cshtml", storeViewModel );
}

public ActionResult CreateNewStoreTax()
{
   var storeTaxViewModel = new StoreTaxViewModel();
   return PartialView( "~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/StoreTaxViewModel.cshtml", storeTaxViewModel );
}
```

How can I structure my application to deal with such complex nesting dynamic templates?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you managed to solve this issue? I am currently running into a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your editor template you're doing the following:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => @Model.taxName)
```

Whereas you *should* be doing:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.taxName)
```

Also, FWIW, you don't need to iterate over the items an call `@Html.EditorFor(model => @Model.NewStores[i])` for each. Just do:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewStores)
```

Razor will automatically render the editor template for each item in the collection.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I added your suggestion and no change. The lists of StoreTaxes objects inside the Store object is still not populating.